# connection issues when running Kakfa test container with Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, testcontainers

I am facing connection issues when running Kakfa test container(confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.3) with Spring Boot App. Wondering if someone has faced this issue as well. After kafka container starts, the Admin Client tries to connect to broker to fetch the metadata but fails to connect.
Error log:

```
[AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I tried following workarounds to ensure  KafkaAdminClient uses right address but none of them worked:

1. Used boot strap server address
2. Used KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=BROKER://172.17.0.3:9092. This address was being set by testcontainers_start.sh within docker container
3. Used kafa.getContainerName() to form the address: Example: BROKER://t-adsad:9092
4. Used kafka.getHost() + “:” + kafka.getMappedPort(9092)

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import(KafkaTestContainersConfiguration.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
public class KafkaTestContainersLiveTest {    
    @ClassRule
    public static KafkaContainer kafka =
            new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.3"));

    @BeforeClass
    public static  void setupBootstrapServer(){
        String server = "BROKER://"+kafka.getNetworkAliases().get(0)+":9092";
        System.setProperty("kafka.bootstrap.servers", server);
    }
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaTestContainersConfiguration {
    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap.servers}")
    private String bootstrapServer;

    @Value("${kafka.topic}")
    private String topic;

    public final int NUM_PARTITIONS=1;
    public final short REPLICATION_FACTOR=1;


    @Bean
    public AdminClient adminClient() {
        return KafkaAdminClient.create(adminClientConfigs());
    }

    public Map<String, Object> adminClientConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
        props.put(AdminClientConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 5000);
        return props;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your actual test code and the properties that start with the container? Secondly, do you really need a container vs using EmbeddedKafka with `spring-kafka`?

Comment: The source code uses SSL to connect to kafka broker and as far as I know EmbeddedKafka does not support SSL. That's why I started with TestContainers. I have also read that tests can fail with EmbeddedKafka due to port conflicts.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have updated the post with the test code. Thanks.

Comment: So, you will need to set `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` and `KAFKA_LISTENERS`... Where are you setting these?

Comment: The `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS ` is set by testcontainers_start.sh within the docker test container. `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS='PLAINTEXT://localhost:32926,BROKER://IP:9092'`                                                                                                                        
 Kakfa container class sets `KAFKA_LISTENERS`default value to `withEnv("KAFKA_LISTENERS", "PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:" + KAFKA_PORT + ",BROKER://0.0.0.0:9092");`

Comment: So, why are you using `+":9092"`?  The port seems to be `32926`. Why cant you use `kafka.getBootstrapServers()` as it is documented instead of using the network alias method?

Comment: I have tried using bootstrap server address as well but same issue happens. `32926` is the port on which broker runs within the container. `9092` is the port exposed for external process to connect.

Comment: Unclear how you are exposing the port to anything different than the one it binds to via the ClassRule...  By default the `cp-kafka` container doesn't have any such `testcontainers_start.sh` script, so can you provide links or docs that you're referencing? I know for a fact there have been [multiple blogs](https://www.confluent.io/blog/advanced-testing-techniques-for-spring-kafka/) and [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O968f81LTeY) doing exactly what you're trying to accomplish here